# Determine if a function is a discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am struggling in understanding why U is not a discrete random variable and V is. Here is the problem:

Let $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space in which
$\Omega = ${1,2,3,4,5,6}, F={ $\emptyset$, {2,4,6}, {1,3,5}, $\Omega$} and let U,V be functions on $\Omega$ defined by 
$U(\omega)=\omega$, $V(\omega)=$ 1 if $\omega$ is even, 0 if $\omega$ is odd,
for $\omega \in \Omega$. Determine which of U,V are discrete random variables on the probability space.

Within my textbook it states that U is not a discrete random but V is. I am just confused about this because if U is defined on the elements of $\Omega$ and we have an underlying probability space, then shouldn't the probability of this functions outcomes just be the probability that a singular $\omega$ occurs?

From my understanding of what a discrete random variable is it states that we are taking the elements from $\Omega$ and mapping it to some real number. So then are we just treating the elements of $\Omega$ as outcomes and not as the numbers as they are?

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are both discrete random variables, by any reasonable definition of the word discrete.

Comment: Random variables are measurable functions $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ (not $\Omega\to\Omega$). $V:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable because $V$ is measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$. This is not the case for $U$. For instance the preimage of $U$ of Borel set $\{1\}$ is (again) $\{1\}$ which is not an element of $F$.

Comment: So for U to be a random variable I would need $F$ to be the power set of $\Omega$. This is because we cannot determine the probability of {1} occuring because we dont have the complement of {1}?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. $U$ is only measurable if $F$ contains the preimage (wrt $U$) of every Borel set.

Comment: Thank you for the help!